# Jquery Why is this var definition giving uncaught exception

Tags: jquery, var

Console.log is giving uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #.
This seems to be caused by `$('#'+elmid+' div')`. if i remove # then i do not get this error. What is causing this.

```
$(".abs").live('click',
function(e) {
    var elmid = $(this).attr('id');
    var editableid = $('#'+elmid+' div').attr('id');
    console.log(editableid);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the clicked element does not actually have an `id` attribute.  This means that your selector is `# div`, which is obviously an invalid jQuery selector. You should use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead:

```
var editableid = $(this).find('div').attr('id');
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm getting this error because one of the div elements does not have an ID. Thanks for pointing this out.